unrecognized comments in newtcblistings enviroment
I have defined an environment for various shell scripts.  I have other configuration files I want to do the same thin with.
When I try to use \tcbuselibrary{listings} and define an environment for shell code and I call it like this:
\begin{shellcode}
  # simple loop example
  for file in *.txt
  do
  echo ``file:''$file
  done
\end{shellcode}

\begin{OpenBSDPF}

latex gives me this error:
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \next.
 
                   }
l.93   #
         simple loop example

When I escape all the '#' as follows:
  \# simple loop example
  for file in *.txt
  do
  echo ``file:''$file
  done
\end{shellcode}

\begin{OpenBSDPF}
  \# PF Configuration
  \# ANTISPOOF **QUICK**

then I get this error:

Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
 
                \par 
 pf_and_dhcp.tex

here is the pertinent code:
% Define PF language
\lstdefinelanguage{OpenBSDPF}{
  morekeywords={pass,block,in,out,log,quick,on,proto,from,to,port,rdr,nat,table,scrub,anchor},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{\#},
  morestring=[b]"
}

% Define DHCPd language
\lstdefinelanguage{DHCPd}{
  morekeywords={option,subnet,range,host,fixed-address,hardware,filename,authoritative},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{\#},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]'
}

% Define a custom environment for OpenBSDPF with rounded corners
\newtcblisting{OpenBSDPF}[1][]{%
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=OpenBSDPF,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color{gray},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        breaklines=true,
        #1 % Allow optional arguments for listings options
    },
    colback=lightgray!20,    % Background color
    colframe=black,          % Border color
    arc=3mm,                 % Rounded corners
    boxrule=0.5pt,           % Border thickness
    bottom=1mm,              % Adjust padding
    top=1mm
}

% Define a custom environment for DHCPd with rounded corners
\newtcblisting{DHCPd}[1][]{%
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=DHCPd,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color{gray},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        breaklines=true,
        #1 % Allow optional arguments for listings options
    },
    colback=lightgray!20,    % Background color
    colframe=black,          % Border color
    arc=3mm,                 % Rounded corners
    boxrule=0.5pt,           % Border thickness
    bottom=1mm,              % Adjust padding
    top=1mm
}

% Define a custom environment for shellcode with rounded corners
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcblisting{shellcode}[1][]{%
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=bash,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        commentstyle=\color{green},
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        captionpos=b,
        #1 % Allow optional arguments for listings options
    },
    colback=lightgray!20,    % Background color
    colframe=black,          % Border color
    arc=3mm,                 % Rounded corners
    boxrule=0.5pt,           % Border thickness
    bottom=1mm,              % Adjust padding
    top=1mm
}

and here's how I call it:
\begin{shellcode}
  # simple loop example
  for file in *.txt
  do
  echo ``file:''$file
  done
\end{shellcode}

\begin{OpenBSDPF}
  # PF Configuration
  # ANTISPOOF **QUICK**
  antispoof log quick for { $ext_if } inet
  pass in on $int_if from any proto tcp to 192.168.24.2 port 22
  pass in on egress proto tcp from any to any port 80
  block in on egress from 192.168.1.0/24 to any
  rdr pass on egress proto tcp from any to 192.168.1.100 port 22 -> 10.0.0.1 port 2222
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{shellcode}
  # simple loop example
  for file in *.txt
  do
  echo ``file:''$file
  done
\end{shellcode}

\begin{OpenBSDPF}
  # PF Configuration
  # ANTISPOOF **QUICK**
  antispoof log quick for { $ext_if } inet
  pass in on $int_if from any proto tcp to 192.168.24.2 port 22
  pass in on egress proto tcp from any to any port 80
  block in on egress from 192.168.1.0/24 to any
  rdr pass on egress proto tcp from any to 192.168.1.100 port 22 -> 10.0.0.1 port 2222
\end{lstlisting}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The comment issue is a limitation of \newtcblisting. The tcolorbox manual mentions the following in section 17.3 on page 333 (for version 6.4.1 2024/10/22):

If a new sort of tcblisting environments should be created with one optional argument only, one is highly recommended to use \DeclareTCBListing→ P. 335 or \NewTCBListing→ P. 335 instead of \newtcblisting to avoid content scanning problems.

The comment parsing issue that you encounter is one of those 'content scanning problems'. The solution therefore is to rewrite the \newtcblisting definition into a \NewTCBListing definition (note that command names in LaTeX are case-sensitive, so these are two different commands).
There is an example of usage of \NewTCBListing on page 335, using O{} to specify the optional argument instead of [1][] as in the code with \newtcblisting. The rest of the definition can remain as it is. However, the manual also mentions (on page 336):

With date of 2018-05-12, the xparse package changed the argument collection
process (now part of the LATEX kernel). Spaces are ignored which leads to a serious change for listing environments ending with an optional argument like O{}. The former behavior of respecting spaces can be preserved by adding a «!». Note that the following code uses !O{} now.

Combining these two remarks:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\NewTCBListing{shellcode}{ !O{} }{%
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=bash,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        commentstyle=\color{green},
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        captionpos=b,
        #1 % Allow optional arguments for listings options
    },
    colback=lightgray!20,    % Background color
    colframe=black,          % Border color
    arc=3mm,                 % Rounded corners
    boxrule=0.5pt,           % Border thickness
    bottom=1mm,              % Adjust padding
    top=1mm
}
\begin{document}
\begin{shellcode}
  # simple loop example
  for file in *.txt
  do
  echo ``file:''$file
  done
\end{shellcode}
\end{document}

Result:

